# python watchdog monitor file on the server

Tags: python, python-3.x, watchdog

From watchdog it allow me to monitor file change on the machine which I am running the script (my PC), but how can I do if want to monitor the file is on another server (unix) which allow access via ssh.

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # I want to monitor file on the server which allow access via ssh.
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.' 
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: Can you not run the script on the server?

Comment: I cannot run run script on the server, but I can access to server via ssh.

Comment: So the server does not provide a shell? Is this rsync over ssh or such? If you can't get the script to run on the machine that has access to the filesystem to be watched (so that it can use filesystem change notification), you have to use polling instead.

Comment: you give some info of code, I run shell script and python script, but I cannot install for example watchdog lib , only python 2.7 is there.